# How can you convert weighted average MongoDB Query into Spring Data Query?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, average, aggregation

I have the following Aggregation and want to use it into my Spring-Project, where I use SpringData.
The Aggregation looks like the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $group : {
     _id : 'weighted average', 
     numerator: {  $sum: { $multiply: [ "a", "b"] } },
     denominator: { $sum: "a" }
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    average: { $divide: [ "$numerator", "$denominator" ] }
  }
})
```

To sum up: I want to calculate as a numerator the sum of multiple multiplications: e.g. a1*b1 + a2*b2 + ....=?
As the denominator i want a sum over all a's, e.g a1+a2+a3+a4+...=?
Then i also want to divide the numerator with the denominator.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the spring data mongdb aggregation code

```
List<AggregationOperation> stages = new ArrayList<>();

Multiply multiplyOp = ArithmeticOperators
        .valueOf("$a").multiplyBy("$b");

GroupOperation  groupOperation = group(Aggregation.fields("_id")).sum(multiplyOp).as("numerator").sum("a").as("denominator")

Divide divideOp = ArithmeticOperators.valueOf("$numerator")
        .divideBy("$denominator");

ProjectOperation projectOperation = project().and(divideOp).as("average");

stages.add(groupOperation);

stages.add(projectOperation);

newAggregation(stages);
```